# Const inside for loop

Tags: typescript

So I was writing a for loop in typescript like this:

```
for (let item of itemList) {
    …
}
```

But since I have tsLint installed it recommended me to use `const`insted of `let`.

Is this a good recommendation? I mean it works with `const` but is this something you should do?

Comment: It depends on the functionality you're after, whether you want to assign anything to your `item` variable or not.

Comment: Note that if that's being triggered by the `prefer-const` rule, you'll only get that "error" from ESLint if you never assign to `item` within the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a good recommendation? I mean it works with const but is this something you should do?

It's entirely up to you and your team.

Using `const` there means you can't assign to `item` within the loop body:

```
for (const item of itemList) {
    item = item.toUpperCase(); // Error
    // ...
}
```

Using `let` there means you can:

```
for (let item of itemList) {
    item = item.toUpperCase(); // Works (well, if it's a string or...)
    // ...
}
```

(Note that that assignment does **not** change `itemList`, just the variable within the loop body.)

Whether you want to prevent assignment to `item` within the loop body is both a matter of style and dependent on what the code within the body does.

---

Just for the avoidance of doubt: The `const` applies to the *binding* (loosely, "variable" — e.g., `item`). If `itemList` is an iterable of objects, for instance, `const` does **not** mean you can't change the state of the objects `item` points to.

```
const itemList = [
    {foo: 1},
    {foo: 2}
];
for (const item of itemList) {
    item.foo *= 2;  // Works
}
```

---

For what it's worth, built-in ESLint rules generally have an explanation of why the ESLint maintainers think the rule is useful. In this case, I suspect it's the [`prefer-const` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const), which gives this reasoning:

> If a variable is never reassigned, using the `const` declaration is better.
>
> `const` declaration tells readers, "this variable is never reassigned," reducing cognitive load and improving maintainability.

Again, it's up to you / your team whether you agree with that reasoning.

Comment: FWIW, I go into this in some depth in Chapter 2 of my new book, see my profile for links.